# How to get content of WebResponse?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I want to get a HttpStatusCode and HttpWebResponse content from HttpWebResponse. For the HttpStatusCode I use `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode`, of course it works correctly. For content, I use `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream`, but it gives me a `MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream`.

```
using (var stream = webResp.GetResponseStream())
{
  var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
  responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

`ReadToEnd()` throw System.NotSupportedException

Comment: I certainly need the status and the content.

Comment: Probably the encoding is incorrect..
Try this overload..
new StreamReader(stream, true);